# Problem booting into my system: cryptsetup: lvm is not available

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with full disk encryption using [this](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu) guide. Normally I have to enter one passphrase to unlock `root` and then another one to unlock `swap`, and then the system boots with no issues (`home` gets unlocked automatically). But today, after successfully unlocking `root`, I got the passphrase for `swap` wrong a couple of times and then got the following message: `cryptsetup: lvm is not available`. I tried shutting down the system several times to enter both passphrases again, but after one attempt I got again the same message. This happened to me some time ago, and the only solution I could find was to reinstall the system again.

So my question is: What could have happened to my system and how can I fix it without reinstalling the system again?

I am absolutely sure I know the correct passphrases, so I think this is not the issue.

If it is helpfull, I have a backup of my partitions' LUKS headers (as suggested in the guide) in a safe place. Will restoring the LUKS headers solve my problem?

Also, please take into account that I am a very basic user and can only reliably follow step-by-step guides.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to bindmount /dev. For me, it would not work until id did that.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that your suggestion is relevant to this question, and then provide the step-by-step instructions that were requested?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I would have loved to add that as a comment to another answer but because of my missing reputation, I couldn't.

Comment: In the answer below, two bindmounts are shown. To make that answer work, /dev also needs to be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

**hi there,this might help you:**

I got the same on xubuntu 16.04, be patient just follow these steps and it will help you so much:

the failure:

the message **“cryptsetup: lvm not available”** after set the first password is due to swap partition corrupted.

check starting from usb or live cd and running **gparted**, identify your hard disk (booting from a live system should be **/sda**, it may change if there are more than one disk attached in your system)

select the main ubuntu installation disk, you will find the failed partition looking in to the field **“file system”**, it shows “unknown” for the corrupted partition (swap).

Fixing the problem:

stay on the live session

1. from **gparted** select this “unknown” partition and delete it. Create a new one, no matter if ext2, ext3 or ext4. The new partition name may change, please don’t forget that name ( /sda# ). Close **gparted**.
2. Open a shell and type:

blkid

notice the line containing the partition created at item 1, it looks like this:

```
/dev/sda#: UUID="acc7a537-a71e-47e1-9f5e-231bb273bae6" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="000c06c7-05"
```

copy the UUID shown on your machine for the new partition **/dev/sda#**.

3. crypts by using **cryptsetup luks format** ,  on shell type:

   cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 2000 /dev/sda#

   it will request a password, follow the application.
4. open the new luks crypted partition as swap:

   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda# swap
5. format this luks partition as a swap partition, type on shell:

   mkswap /dev/mapper/swap
6. open the luks partition /dev/sda2 ( the root partition on the original system) as root , type on shell:

   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 root
7. from the live session prepare to chroot into the  original installed system. Recall our system partition is /dev/sda2, known to Cryptsetup simply as root. The boot partition is /dev/sda1 on the original system.

   mkdir mnt/

   cd /mnt

   mkdir root

   mount /dev/mapper/root root

   mount /dev/sda1 root/boot
8. Now do the actual changeroot and mount some needed filesystem points.

   chroot root

   mount -t proc proc /proc

   mount -t sysfs sys /sys
9. edit the original crypttap. Write the new UUID (UUID copied on item 2) replacing the old one for the swap partition, fallow these steps:

   nano /etc/crypttab

the shell  will show the crypted UUIDs  just like this:

```
root UUID=b61e1bf7-01e0-43e9-b5cd-19b3dc708343 none luks
swap UUID=b0be04e5-086b-4236-91b2-3489878bb9e5 none cipher=twofish-xts-plain64,size=512,hash=sha512,swap
home UUID=acc7a537-a71e-47e1-9f5e-231bb273bae6 none luks
```

carefully replace the new crypted swap partition UUID

save and close nano

10. generate a new boot filesystem image and exit the chroot.

    update-initramfs -u

    exit
11. close the live session , restart the system , good-luck.